# Using Model Class to get data that has no type from web api in C#

Tags: c#, json, api

I am working an on API C# project.

I have some problems to get data from the API response.

This is the API's response:

```
{
    "AMZN": {
        "assetType": "EQUITY",
        "assetMainType": "EQUITY",
        "cusip": "023135106",
        "symbol": "AMZN"
    },
    "HCAT": {
        "assetType": "EQUITY",
        "assetMainType": "EQUITY",
        "cusip": "42225T107",
        "symbol": "HCAT"
    },
    "GRNF": {
        "assetType": "EQUITY",
        "assetMainType": "EQUITY",
        "cusip": "36257K109",
        "symbol": "GRNF"
    },
    "AAPL": {
        "assetType": "EQUITY",
        "assetMainType": "EQUITY",
        "cusip": "037833100",
        "symbol": "AAPL"
    }
}
```

And I want to get this data into my model class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Leviathan.Models.JSON
{
    class QuoteModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("assetType")]
        public string AssetType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("assetMainType")]
        public string AssetMainType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cusip")]
        public string Cusip { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("symbol")]
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But I can't get data from this API with that class.

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks, regards.

Comment: You can deserialize this json to `Dictionary<string, QuoteModel>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class looks good, you can use Newtonsoft to `Deserialize` the json into the class.

```
var quotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, QuoteModel>(apiResponse);
```

This will take the json string (api response) and `Deserialize` it into the class that you created. You need a `Dictionary` to store the ticker symbol and the values will be stored into the class properties themselves.

Comment: Thanks. Could you send Dictionry content?

Comment: What do you mean? Like reading materials? Here is a link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks again, there are no method to get with class?

Comment: If you have the Newtonsoft dll and the using namespace, you can use the code that I posted and it will work. Check this out to see. https://dotnetfiddle.net/NxhFwk

Comment: Make sure you have `System.Collections.Generic` as a using directive.

Comment: Thanks. it is solved with your answer.